# If I compile Java app at another location it can not read from any folder

Tags: java

I have an app. Which is in RC state. I've started finalizing works by splitting the classes to separate files with appropriate import sets at another location but suddenly I've found that cleaner version cannot read from any folder. So I investigated that if I compile the code in another location except the actual (original) app cannot read from any folder.

Strange is that from folders from those cannot be read can be obtained path (subdirectories included).

I have packed this app to executable jar file before started this works. Maybe somewhere in JVM is something stuck?

Note: New files are compiled without error. I've tried both original source and new sources.

Failure is in methods File.list() or File.listFiles(). The same using directory stream.

Used packages:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

import java.io.LineNumberReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FilenameFilter;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
```

For sure at this part:

```
private void loadFiles(){
    cesta=folderPicker.getSelectedFile();       
    if(folder==null||loadedCesta!=cesta||(cesta==folderPicker.getSelectedFile()&vetsiPismoVisible==true)){      
    folder=new File(cesta.getName());       

    String datFiles[]=folder.list(new FilenameFilter() {
public boolean accept(File folder, String fileName) {
    return fileName.endsWith(".dat");}});
```

If I try:
    folder.canRead()
on every folder on my PC and also e.g.on my workstation these new compilations get false as a result. Variable:
    folderPicker
is reffering to JFileChooser that is limited to folders and folders are obtained via actionListener of special JButton (not classic Open and Cancel). You can try it from Karolina_RC.jar from link provided in commentary under conditions said.

Comment: well not much info is provided, but my best guess is that you are trying to access files that are packed in .jar file using File.list() which is not possible

Comment: If possible - please provide more info. What is the directory structure and packages like in your two programs? Which file(s) are you trying to read?

Comment: I have structure like this C:\Java Codes\Karolína\ where is the source code located in one file. It the folder is app compiled and also in the same folder is created exe. jar. At location C:\Java Codes\Karolína\Final\ I have source split into 3 source files (one per class). If I complied the source no matter which one at other location than the first one mentioned methods return still null.

Comment: Here the file http://uloz.to/xVXSzJow/zip-zip pass: dat90_X. It should works with files with .dat extension (simple past it any non-empty .dat file a it will somehow work).

Comment: Please edit your question to include an SSCCE  http://sscce.org/

Comment: RC state mean that is almost done. I wanted split it to separate class, correct some small mistakes a make it commented. Than make exe. jar. I think that there is no formal problem.

Comment: I definitely do not try access files in jar archive. For accessing files is used folder which is get from JFileChooser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. For some reason is no longer possible to use only folder name to make File type (folder). Now it is required to use path.

E.g.

```
File folder=new File(path.getName());
File folder=new File(path.getPath());
```

Former no longer working. Latter does. I am guessing some JVM-compile issue.

Comment: You are guessing wrong.  Those two methods do different things.  `getName()` returns only the *last* segment of the name, so calling it for `/foo/bar/baz.txt` will return `baz.txt`.  `getPath()` returns the full representation that the `File` object was created with.  If you created it with `baz.txt` you'll get `baz.txt`, but if you call it with `/foo/bar/baz.txt` you'll get `/foo/bar/baz.txt`.  What you probably *really* want is `getCanonicalPath()`, which is both absolute, and unique.

Comment: To sum up your real problem, `getName()` will work fine as long as all of the folders you want to work with are contained in the same folder that you're running the program from, but will fail if you start the program from a different folder.  `getPath()` will work as long as `path` is *absolute*.

Comment: The problems was quite different but in fact it is matter of File class type object creation as you both said. Once again if I compile app in its actual location using only folder name it can works will all folders. If I move it before compilation to another it can works with no one. But for the first case there is an issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33758727/why-list-from-file-class-returns-list-for-folders-sharing-same-parent-folder so the second or the second with getCanonicalPath() is the right one.

Comment: Where you compile it does not matter.  Where you *run* it from does.  Relative paths are understood relative to the current working directory.  You should pretty much always use `getCanonicalPath()`